# Confused about advice from Coleman about seasoning their porcelain coated cast iron grill grates

Tags: cleaning, cast-iron, grilling, maintenance

Basically, I thought porcelain coated grates don't need to be seasoned, but the official instructions from the Coleman page explicitly recommend it.

I've got a Coleman grill for 3 years now and I think my grates are starting to rust. I'm wondering if I messed up the maintenance...

I'd always put on oil before grilling, then after grilling burn off excess bits on high heat for 20 min or so. And over fall and winter I'd always take the grates inside.

I'd appreciate some coherent cleaning and maintenance tips so I don't mess up the grates further if I either get rid of the rust or buy replacement grates.

Comment: Are you sure it's rust?  And not built-up burned on crud?

Comment: Took a wire brush to a small localized area to see if it'd come off, and it didn't, so I assume it's "in" the material.

Comment: ‘Burning off’ everything may have caused the porcelain to crack and flake off.  And it tends to carbonize seasoning (a crazy hot grill is one of the recommended methods to strip nasty cast iron)

Comment: Got it. I was following advice from different sources... ever since Canada quasi-banned steel brushes, I find that cleaning the BBQ just doesn't work as well. Those plastic or wood bristles sometimes just don't cut it.

Comment: My personal solution would be to just used the grates for one more season and then replace them.  I've generally found cast iron grates -- enameled or not -- to have about a 3-year useful lifespan (which was one of my reasons for getting the expensive cast Alumninum grates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, porcelain coated cast iron doesn't need to be seasoned. What would be the point?  I do see on the Coleman website where they recommend seasoning.  I wonder if their advice is somehow related to warranty legalities.

If you are seeing rust, I am assuming that some of the porcelain has worn off.  The rust is happening because you have bare cast iron.  ***That*** is what seasoning could help...just like a cast iron pan.  Clean it well, wipe on some oil, hold at high temp for 10-20 minutes.  You can probably work this into your clean up routine.

You can cook on non-porcelain coated cast iron, so no need to buy replacement grates, unless the breakdown of the porcelain is quite extensive and it bothers you or you notice inconsistent cooking.

Comment: Thanks; for the "clean it well part" I'm also confused by all the advice. If it's rust, I guess I'd need to get aggressive. But with porcelain I understand I don't want to be aggressive. Any advice there?

Comment: I cook on a cast iron grate.  I get occasional rust when I don't use for a while.  I just hit it well with a wire brush, then season.  So, remove any loose stuff...not overly agressive.